# Need to run the command without opening the dos prompt

Tags: java, dos

I have used the following code to make a folder undeletable in my java project. It works fine. When I create an exe of my project the dos prompt doesn't get disappeared.

```
cmd.exe /c start  icacls "folder name" /e /c /d %username%
```

I also tried without opening the dos prompt. But it doesn't work.

```
icacls ONGX32/winkrl /e /c /d %username%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple way. Created a .bat temporary file consists of that command. Used that .bat file. It didn't open the command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Instead use:

```
cmd /c icacls "folder name" /e /c /d %username%
```

`start` is sort of the same as `cmd /c`, so you don't need both.

Comment: It throws the following IOEXCEPTION  "Cannot run program "start": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified"

Comment: Actually, I made a mistake. `start` is a cmd command, not an executable. You don't need `start`, but you do need `cmd /c`. I am updating the answer above for the record.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `%username%` is replaced by its value by cmd.exe.

You need to get it with `System.getenv("username")`, and replace it yourself in the command string.

**Edit**. You may also need to use the fully qualified path to *icacls.exe*.

Answer (score 0):

In a command prompt, the command `exit` closes it.

You can run [multiple commands on one line](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/279253) using the `&&` command separator.

It should be something like this:

```
cmd /c icacls "folder name" /e /c /d %username% && exit
```